# How to loop through an array(of prompts) and answer each prompt one at a time before continuing loop?

Tags: c, loops, logic

Hello I'm obviously new to C but I'm looking for some help or advice on the logic behind what I want to do. 
That being, I'm going to make an array of questions and I'd like to loop through it and print out the questions one at a time. 
The catch is that after one question is printed out the program or function waits until it is answered with a "Y" or "N" then the loop continues. Once all questions are answered the results are printed and the program ends.

I just need some advice on the logic behind something like this. Perhaps the use of loops in this instance isn't feasible and I need to try something different, any advice is appreciated!

Comment: This question is too vague. What are you having trouble with? printing the questions? reading the answers? storing the answers?

Comment: Sorry about that, more or less having trouble wrapping my mind around how to loop through print 1 question wait for an answer then continue and loop.

Comment: If you already know how to loop through your elements, you can use `char *gets(char *s)` to capture the answer.

Comment: Okay great and how would I prevent the loop from printing all the questions before an answer is entered?

Comment: FAll the basic input-reading functions make the program wait until they get thir input and return the result.

Comment: Alright much appreciated,thanks. That's all the advice I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one of a possible multitude of options (you asked for C, so, here's some C code; in C++, this could have been done entirely differently):

1. You need to define a structure to hold your questions, maybe like this:

   ```
   #define QUESTION_SZ 128 /* adjust to your needs, or use dynamic memory allocation */
   #define ANSWER_SZ 128 /* ditto */
   struct question
   {
       char question_text[QUESTION_SZ]; 
       char answer[ANSWER_SZ];
   };
   ```
2. Then, you may create an array of questions and initialize it:

   ```
   struct question my_poll[32];
   ```
3. Next, you may loop through your array of questions and handle them:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   char *p = NULL;
   int oops_we_failed = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
   {
       printf("Question %d: %s. Your answer?\n", i, my_poll[i].question);

       /* fgets() will block until user enters an answer */
       p = fgets(my_poll[i].answer, ANSWER_SZ, stdin);

       if(NULL == p)
       {
           /* nothing was read, an error could have happened */
           oops_we_failed = 1;
           break;
       }
       else
       {
           /* now we have a possible answer stored in poll[i].answer */
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now you have an array of questions and corresponding answers.

You may need to study linked lists to dynamically create polls of arbitrary length.